# execute Bash script on form submission through browser in php

Tags: php, html, bash

I am trying to execute bash command(to open an application in system) via a browser in php.

(Example) If I run the command in terminal it opens up Shotwell(image viewer) and displays the image.

I want to display image using shotwell in my system when I submit my form. How do I do this?

Here is my code. Why doesn't it work?

form.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
        exec('shotwell bike.jpg');
 }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method=post>
  Store ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <br>
  Department ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="emailID" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use exec? It can be done with img tag.  echo "<img src='shotwell bike.jpg' /> \n";

Comment: Yes I know that I can display image using img tag. I want to open an application present in the system through this way I took Shotwell as an example. I am wondering what is wrong in the script? Ideally, Image viewer should pop up on submission but I don't know what is wrong here?

Comment: cant exec be used in this way? Is it only used to store the outputs as a string for bash commands?

Comment: You are calling `exec` from the server process, which does not have access to your X-Server. Is this Apache? You would have to connect to the X-Server you want the application to show on, but I don't think the whole thing is a good idea. Why are you trying to do it?

Comment: yes, it's apache. I am just doing some DIY in my learning, embedding bash in php. other commands worked but this kind of commands didn't work. So I was wondering why and posted. Thanks to you now I know why. @KarstenKoop